# Meaning of Intercept and what the intercept should be with no measurement error?

Tags: regression, residuals, excel, intercept

I'm going into University this year, Engineering to be more specific and I was given an assignment over the summer about regression. (Something I have no knowledge about) Basically, in my questions I have two questions that I have no idea about answering. Here they are...

1. I need to describe the significance of the intercept. In my thing on excel I have a few different kinds from what I can see. Theres an image attached so you can see. I have things like "Coefficient, t Stat, P-value..." Whats the significance of the intercept? For this assignment its basically about finding the Total Energy, Total Charge, Power, and I^2 (By the way, what would you call I^2?) from the elapsed time, Voltage, and Current in a series circuit. **I highlighted in blue the intercept and standard error in the image**[image]
2. This one is hard, I cannot find anything to help me...What should the intercept be if there are no measurement errors?

Please any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You should add the `self-study` tag as this is homework. Have you read any simple explanations of linear regression, such as [this](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/regression/intro.html)? Have you plotted the data used for each regression to see what they look like? That might help illuminate these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

There are two relationships in mathematics that unfortunately have their terminology often mixed up.  A **linear** relationship is governed by an equation of the form:

$$
y = a \cdot x.
$$

An **affine** relationship is governed by an equation of the form:

$$
y = a \cdot x + b.
$$

The intercept in the affine equation is $b$.  Of course, if $y$ has a linear relationship with $x$, it also has an affine relationship with $x$ (with $b$ = 0).  Certain things in life/nature *truly have linear relationships*, for example,

- $y =$ length of an object measured in inches
- $x =$ length of an object measured in feet

$$
y = 12 \cdot x.
$$

Unfortunately, **linear regression** typically refers to finding the affine relationship which "best" describes the data.  If we had some error in our measurements, and ran a linear regression, we might get results like:

$$
y = 12.1 \cdot x - 1.25.
$$

I hope this was helpful.  I didn't want to address the question too directly.  Let me know if you have any questions.

PS:  Did it say statistical significance or just significance in (1)?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, it asked for "physical significance" if that helps

Comment: I'm assuming it has to be with the series circuit itself. So what significance it would have on the circuit but that seems weird. (But I may be wrong)